# SQL Server - memory usage per database level and query level

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am trying to find a query for two things:

1. Get Current Memory Usage  per database

There are different databases at the same server so I need to get Memory Usage for specific database, not for all dbs.

2. Get Current Memory Usage per query

I want to compare different queries, how much memory they consume so I can evaluate if some queries needs to be optimized in a meaning that they consume too much memory and not whether they take too much time.

Comment: Database don't use memory, unless you are specifically using in-memory databases; but you don't state that.

Comment: Ahh ok, fair enough so thats why everythihng is for server level.

Comment: @Larnu, what about memory per query level, is that possible?

Comment: Have a look at [Monitor memory usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/monitor-memory-usage?view=sql-server-ver15), which might answer some of your questions. It's far from as simple as "how much memory did a query use?"

Comment: Had already been looking at this  but its per server level. I actually can see that in the activity monitor , there is all the information, as well as memory info per query but I cannot find the sql behind this "Activity monitor" and I dont have privilidges to get Activity monitor info(I saw the results only on my local instance) .
Any idea how to find this sql behind activity monitor dashboard in SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks Aaron, this seems to show some memory per database. What about per query level?

Comment: @gk1993_aal added an answer - check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Get Current Memory Usage per database

Use below link, download "Memory - BufferPoolSize.sql" and install stored procedure `BufferPoolSize` on any database. Run it and it will show current Buffer Pool size used for each database

https://github.com/aleksey-vitsko/Database-Administrator-Tools

[image: BufferPoolSize]

> Get Current Memory Usage per query

Use below link, download "First Responder Kit", unzip it and install `sp_BlitzCache` into any database

https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/

Run it with below parameter

```
exec sp_BlitzCache @SortOrder = 'memory grants'
```

It will give you a list of queries (that are present in a Plan Cache currently) that used most of memory, when they ran

Comment: Many thanks Aleksey. Is it possible to provide the sql for this task instead? I cannot install anything (privilidges).

Comment: @gk1993_aal you can turn those stored procedures into sql scripts - not hard

Answer (score 1):

-- Memory used by each database

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id),
COUNT (1) * 8 / 1024 AS MBUsed
FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
GROUP BY database_id
ORDER BY COUNT (*) * 8 / 1024 DESC
GO
```